# How to use VoidedPurchases API together with Real Time Developer Notifications?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-developer-api, google-play-billing

If a server is already listening to Real Time Developer Notifications what’s the benefit to also poll the Voided Purchases API?

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases) say:

> Note: Unlike other order-related data sources, the Voided Purchases API includes purchases that are charged back by payment processors. Therefore, you might see inconsistencies between the information from this API and information from other order-related data sources.

This is too vague to draw any conclusions. Does that mean there are scenarios in which a subscription is invalidated which doesn’t trigger a RTDN and is only visible in the Voided Purchases API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Developer Support clarified that the Voided Purchases API is only *an addition* for investigative / preventive purpose to counter refund fraud. For example, a user who subscribes and after a short time triggers a charge back, therefore having used an entitlement for free.

The API is not required to track subscription state, as a refund (like any other cause) triggers a RTDN.

> You may use the Real Time Developer Notification (RTDN) to track any changes on the status of the user's subscription entitlement. Please note that the subscription is immediately revoked when the purchase has been charged back, you can refer to this link for your reference.
>
> Additionally, you may still use the Voided Purchases API as part of your double security, and track the user's behavior to prevent refund abuse on your app.